# How to store a column value in Redshift varchar column with length more than 65535

Tags: amazon-redshift, varchar, maxlength

I tried to load the redshift table but failed on one column- The length of the data column 'column_description'is longer than the length defined in the table. Table: 65535, Data: 86555.

I tried to increase the length of column in RS table, looks like 65535 is the max length RS supports.

Do we have any alternatives to store value in Redshift?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that Redshift doesn't support anything larger and that one shouldn't store large artifacts in an analytic database.  If you are using Redshift for its analytic powers to find specific artifacts (images, files, etc) then these should be stored in S3 and the object key (pointer) should be stored in redshift.